# Java image not showing?

Tags: java, image, swing, jlabel, imageicon

Having a issue trying to display my logo. The picture is saved in the same folder as main.java

```
    ImageIcon im = new ImageIcon("banner.png"); 
    JLabel bam = new JLabel(im); 

    grid.add(bam);
```

Is there a problem in my syntax?

Comment: Looks good to me, is the banner.png image in the right directory?

Comment: same directory as main.java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `ImageIcon im = new ImageIcon(new File("banner.png"));` If you're using eclipse, put it in the root folder, not the src folder. The root folder has the src folder and the bin folder.

Comment: Why `ImageIcon(new File(...))`? `ImageIcon(String)` is considered a file reference any way?

Comment: MY initial point was to put the image in the root folder...I should've started my answer with that.

Comment: Doesn't like the argument

Comment: I should also point out, there is no such constructor for `ImageIcon(File)` ;) - Not disputing your second part of your answer, apart from the fact we have no idea what the OP is using ;)

Answer (score 6):

There are any number of possible issues, but the likely one is, the location of the image is not within the same context as where the application is being executed from.

Let's say, `main.java` lives in some directory (lets just say "path/to/class" for argument sake), then when you execute you `main.java`, the path to the images would become something like `/path/to/class`, meaning you should be using using something like...

```
ImageIcon im = new ImageIcon("path/to/class/banner.png");
```

This also assumes that the image hasn't being Jar'ed yet, as `ImageIcon(String)` expects a path to a file on the file system.

If the program has being Jar'ed then you won't be able use `ImageIcon(String)`, as the `banner.png` is no longer a file, but a resource, then you would need to use something like...

```
ImageIcon im = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/path/to/class/banner.png"));
```

Where `/path/to/class` is the package where `main.java` lives.

In either case, I would recommend that you use `ImageIO.read` instead, as this will actually throw an `IOException` when something goes wrong, where `ImageIcon` tends to fail silently...

Take a look at [Reading/Loading an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) for more details

Answer (score 1):

If you create a folder called images (or whatever name you prefer) in your source directory, and then place the banner.png file in that folder you can then use the following code.

```
ImageIcon im = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/images/banner.png"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but I had the same issue on my project and fixed it by giving the full path in the `ImageIcon` definition, instead of just the path from the project. I.e.

```
ImageIcon im = new ImageIcon("C:/your/image/file/path/banner.png);
```

It solved the issue for me, **but I do recognise that this is not a valid long-term solution**, since it will only work on the developer's machine and I'm not sure if portability would be an issue.

Hope I have helped somebody.

Answer (score -1):

There's a lot of things that could be going on here and it's hard to tell without more code.  Based on the short snippet above (and assuming everything else is correct) you should check the image load status of the ImageIcon using the [getImageLoadStatus()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html#getImageLoadStatus%28%29) method.  If it returns [MediaTracker.COMPLETE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/MediaTracker.html#COMPLETE) then you're good to go and the error is somewhere outside this code.  If it's anything but COMPLETE then you are having some sort of issue in loading the image.  Maybe it's not in the path or classpath?

Comment: I'm not sure why I was downvoted. The OP asked what could be wrong with his code and depending on disk or network latency it could be a load issue that `MediaTracker` could help with.